# Is it possible to check if a user likes a certain page (on the same domain as the app's domain)?

Tags: php, facebook

I know it's not possible to view likes of users unless they authorize my app, but what if the page is on my domain?
I mean, is there a way I could tell if a user likes a page on my domain?

If not, what are my options? I'd like to display some content only for users that like the page. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access user data if you don't give a access token, even if it's a page on your domain.